# Postgresql function creating ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return name

Tags: function, postgresql

Almost burning out writing this post as a last resort...

Hi all, I am looking to get some help with my first function that I need to create. From what I read I understand you just need to add the function header and footer to any set of SQL commands to create a function.

I have a view that I have created which works fine... here is the code for it

```
CREATE VIEW invoice_v AS 
SELECT customer.firstname, lastname, customer_addresses.address, orders.order_id, order_date, order_total, order_details.product_id, quantity, unitprice, product.product_name
FROM customer, customer_addresses, orders, order_details, product
WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_addresses.customer_id 
AND customer.customer_id = orders.customer_id
AND orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
AND product.product_id = order_details.product_id;

SELECT firstname, lastname, address, order_id, order_date, product_id, product_name, quantity, unitprice, order_total
FROM invoice_v
WHERE order_id = 02;
```

What it does is create a view for an Invoice with all the details for order_id 2.

I need to do a similar thing with a function. Im not sure how this is to be done.

This is what I tried to do... but failed, Im sorry if this seems extremely stupid, but I'm new to this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION invoiceforprint() RETURNS name AS '

SELECT customer.firstname, lastname, customer_addresses.address, orders.order_id, order_date, order_total, order_details.product_id, quantity, unitprice, product.product_name
FROM customer, customer_addresses, orders, order_details, product
WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_addresses.customer_id 
AND customer.customer_id = orders.customer_id
AND orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
AND product.product_id = order_details.product_id;

' LANGUAGE SQL;
```

the code above gives me this error

```
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return name
DETAIL:  Final statement must return exactly one column.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "invoiceforprint"
```

I don't even know what parameter I am supposed to use for the RETURN.
Any help on the matter, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not near a postgres DB so this is untested.

What you are after is called a table function, there is an example here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html

```
CREATE FUNCTION invoiceforprint() RETURNS TABLE(firstname text
       , lastname text
       , address text
       , order_id int
       , order_date date 
       , order_total numeric
       , product_id int
       , quantity numeric
       , unitprice numeric,
       , product_name text ) AS 
$$
SELECT customer.firstname
       , lastname
       , customer_addresses.address
       , orders.order_id
       , order_date
       , order_total
       , order_details.product_id
       , quantity
       , unitprice 
       , product.product_name
FROM customer, customer_addresses, orders, order_details, product
WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_addresses.customer_id 
AND customer.customer_id = orders.customer_id
AND orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
AND product.product_id = order_details.product_id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your message, Just trying out your code, this is the error I am getting...

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 2:        , lastname text
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
SQL state: 42601
Character: 72

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you once again, trying the edited version and this is the result...ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
DETAIL:  Final statement returns too many columns.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "invoiceforprint"

********** Error **********

ERROR: return type mismatch in function declared to return record
SQL state: 42P13
Detail: Final statement returns too many columns.
Context: SQL function "invoiceforprint"

Comment: Return type declaration was missing `product_name` column. Corrected.

Comment: IT WORKED!! HALLELUJA!! THANK YOU Dan & @Tometzky You guys were awesome!